# Dynatrace PurePath: what are each yellow bar?

Tags: performance, query-optimization, monitoring, database-performance, dynatrace

I am using Dynatrace to help orient my efforts as I'm optimizing an endpoint of our service.

Looking at the Controller's PurePath, I am currently wondering: **what does each individual yellow bar mean exactly?**

It seems to be some sort of aggregate since I don't think we have any kind of batching activated. Yet, we see multiple times the same statement being aggregated into one bar, then right after the same statement aggregated again into a single bar, but in the same timeframe (for example: we see a `89x`, then a `90x` following each other).

[image: Dynatrace PurePath]

As per company policy, I had to hide a bunch of things with black rectangles: sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

We have been using Dynatrace for long time now. These yellow boxes are showing the time taken for executing respective query. The query can be seen at the start of that row.
Looking at your diagram it seems you are executing few queries in parallel. e.g. last 4 queries have started at the same time and based on complexity each has taken different time to complete the execution.
The multiplying factor shown as 90X or 89X is the number of times that query is executed. This is what documentation says.

I truly do not agree with that. Why would developer/ DB server run the same query those many times? May be the agent installed on that DB server is getting confused due to same query is getting executed across different requests. This is just my guess.

Regards,
Vikrant Korde

Comment: Are transactions themselves denoted in this graph?

Comment: Which transactions are you referring to? I believe, even in transaction a query would execute only once, until invoked multiple times.

Comment: I'm referring to a DB Transaction. In our case, it could contain multiple queries being executed against the DB multiple times with different values.

Comment: In that case it will show as one execution. Each set of values are counted separately.  Do you think your code is having ~90 different set of values for queries? If yes, then the screen shot is correct.

Comment: What puzzles me is if I have 180 set of values, Dynatrace some times splits those 180 into, *for example*, two consecutive yellow bar (one with 81, and the other with 99). Yet in my code, I see nothing that would split the 180 that way: it would query 180 times separately.

Comment: @payne what technology do you use and how do you execute the queries? Do you execute the queries in one thread or do you execute the queries in an async task (e.g possible in C#)?

Comment: Java, Spring Boot, JPA, JDBC, EclipseLink, Postgres, Nginx. All in one thread.